# Web Api "Optimize Code" breaks routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm having an issue when I build my Web Api project in Release. For some reason, I get a 404 response when I access any web api route. If I turn off 'Optimize Code' for release builds, the routes work as expected. My server is running Windows 2008 R2, IIS 7.5. I'm using ninject for IoC if that matters at all.

I've tried using http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx but I still only get a 404.

This works if running locally (Win7).

Comment: Why the down vote? I'll update with any code samples / logs but not sure what to include at this point.

Comment: Can you include the code for your routes? Just thinking out loud for a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was running into this bug: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1075

The production server was missing some assembly. Although I wasn't able to find it through tracing, fusion logs, etc, after upgrading to 5.2.3, the problem went away.